# Help me assemble a kitchen sink drain

Tags: plumbing

I am trying to assemble a kitchen drain that will have two dishwasher (DW) hookups, one on the garbage disposal (GD) side and one on the second drain side. I have obtained quite hard to find slip joint that has a DW inlet. Problem is, if mounted directly to the sink, it sits too high in relation to GD drain. The gap I need to create is about 1.25”. I know I can add a very short slip joint extension, however bottom end of that extension would just be a regular 1.25” pipe, which I won’t be able to connect to the slip joint with retaining nut and washer.

Easiest way to me would be to use a small extension tailpiece pipe between the sink drain and the drain pipe but I am not sure what is the proper way to do it. Can you help me figure out what is the correct connection type at both sink and the slip joint pictured?

On the photo, I am just holding up the slip joint a little offset to the right, in relation to the drains for illustration. I am also attaching another photo of the part that I think may be a proper way to make this connection but I am not quite sure it is. The thought is that the threaded end will go on the slip joint, and the other end, I will cement the short tailpiece extension. With just 1.25” gap, I’m nit even sure this will work but it’s one possibility I can think of. There has got to be an easier way though.

I already know how I will be connecting it to the GD drain. I will be cutting the slip joint arm and will be using a short pipe with flat end.

I am not well versed with drain part terminology but don’t both ends of this connection require a pipe with flat/flash end? Thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you sure your pipes are 1 1/4" ?  Most kitchen drain assemblies are 1 1/2". -  The adapter in your second image appears to be a GLUE fitting.

Comment: @alaskaman 1.25” in length is how much I need to extend the gap. Pipes are 1 1/2”

Comment: I modified my answer, A tailpiece should get you what you need.

Comment: I'm still a bit unclear what you're asking for, but you can get a slip joint coupler that's slip on both sides which might address your *bottom end of that extension would just be a regular 1.25” pipe* concern - both sides of a slip coupler are slip.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tailpiece   is the solution if the top of the piece in your photo is a slip connection. You may have to get one that has a slip connection on top to accept the tail piece you buy.

If the cut tail piece is to short to work with you can  exchange the long IKEA type basket (*you called it a sink drain*)  for a more [traditional basket](https://www.lowes.com/pd/Keeney-3-5-in-Stainless-Steel-Rust-Resistant-Strainer-Basket-with-Lock-Mount-Included-Basket-Included/3132129), they do not extend down as much.

Then cut down a [6" tail piece](https://www.lowes.com/pd/1-1-2-in-PVC-Sink-tailpiece/1000772378) to give you the distance you need for the dishwasher tail piece.